# Load Runner with multiple users

Tags: c, loadrunner, vugen

I can run only 1 user with 1 terminal at a time then how Load runner handels it when I wanted to use  Multiple user with multiple terminals. (Note: it errored out 4 users).Please suggest any run time settings or any solutions

Comment: Didn't know [loadrunner] ; thought it was the game!

Answer (score 0):

It would help to understand the following:

- What version of LoadRunner?
- What protocol?
- Running on the controller or dedicated load generator?
- "Terminal?"  Please clarify
- Does the same thing happen with an empty virtual user of the same protocol type?
- What version of Windows?